# Set OS X Lion full-screen desktop image programmatically

Tags: cocoa, desktop, osx-lion, background-image, fullscreen

In OS X Lion, when user toggle app full-screen, the window moves to the right to the new space and this new space has a default background.

In QuickTime X, when user toggle full screen, desktop background on the new space that gets created is black.

Is there a code to have a custom desktop image for the newly created space? 
I know that it's possible to change the desktop background of every space in Lion through system preferences but I need not to change it, but to have it already set up when the space gets created for letting the app going full-screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The default linen texture is shown when transitioning an application to a full screen (so that it has it's own space).

It's possible to set different desktop pictures for normal, non-application spaces using the methods available in `NSWorkspace` (i.e. `– setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:`), but they don't really let you control the space that the image is set on – it seems to just set whatever space you're currently on.

So sadly, the answer is no.